# How to Draw a line in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I need to draw a line in UITableviewcell.

There is any possible way to do this one?

If anybody having any idea about to draw a line in UITableview cell please reply me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the line is horizontal or vertical you could add a black UIView. Like this.

```
UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 1)] autorelease];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lineView.autoresizingMask = 0x3f;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

The one above is for one horizontal line. The following code works if you need a vertical line in the middle of the cell

```
UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2), 0, 1, cell.contentView.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];
```

Comment: Seems like that doesn't appear the first time the cell is used. It'd work if I scrolled it out of view though.

Comment: should definitely work the first time a cell appears. Are you using prerelease versions of Xcode or iOS?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to take the image of the line and put it in UIImageView and add the image view to cell's content view... don't go all the way to actually 'drawing' it.. it'll be an overkill..

Comment: I added UILabel with some text in UITableViewCell. Now i need Underline that UILabel text. That only i need to draw line in UITableview cell.