# How to show a divider in a UITableView drag and drop when moving multiple items?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

How can I show a divider in a UITableView drag and drop when moving multiple items in UIKit?

I am trying to achieve a similar outcome like the picture below (please see the blue line separator of where the items will be dropped in Apple's Reminders app0)

[image]

Comment: hi, interesting, it might be possible with a separate view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165409/how-to-draw-a-line-in-uitableviewcell